# Oracle SQL combine results

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+---------------------------+
| col1   | col2    | col3   |
+--------+---------+--------+
| 1      | A       | apple  |
| 1      | A       | banana |
| 2      | B       | grapes |
| 2      | A       | orange |
+--------+---------+--------+
```

What I wanted is to combine all in col3 that has the same col1 and col2

The output that I wanted is like this:

```
+----------------------------------+
| col1   | col2    | col3          |
+--------+---------+---------------+
| 1      | A       | apple, banana |
| 2      | B       | grapes        |
| 2      | A       | orange        |
+--------+---------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, 
    LISTAGG(col3, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col1, col2) AS col3
FROM table_name
GROUP BY col1, col2
ORDER BY col1, col2;
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Thanks bro!!!